# How to get attributes of subclasses with base class pointer

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, subclass, virtual

I have a problem which I encounter again and again in a similar way.

For example:

I have an abstract base class which acts as interface for a series of concrete classes which act as, let's say, data containers.

```
class DataInterface
{
public:
    DataInterface();
    ~DataInterface();

    virtual void FetchData(void) = 0;
    virtual void ProcessData(void) = 0;
    virtual void ClearData(void) = 0;
}
```

The concrete classes would look like this:

```
class BinaryData: public DataInterface
{
public:
    BinaryData();
    ~ BinaryData();

    virtual void FetchData(void);
    virtual void ProcessData(void);
    virtual void ClearData(void);

private:
    bool m_boolData;
}

class IntegerData: public DataInterface
{
public:
    IntegerData();
    ~ IntegerData();

    virtual void FetchData(void);
    virtual void ProcessData(void);
    virtual void ClearData(void);

private:
    int m_intData;
}
```

The subclasses implement the interface which they inherited from DataInterface. But they have different attributes to hold their data. So far so good.

I can use the classes in the main function like that:

```
int main()
{
    int IntegerData;
    bool BoolData;
    DataInterface *pData1 = new BinaryData();
    DataInterface *pData2 = new IntegerData();  

    pData1->FetchData();
    pData2->FetchData();

    pData1->ProcessData();
    pData2->ProcessData();

    // now I want to get the data of pData1 and pData2, for example to write it into a file, show in visualization, ...
    IntegerData = pData2->GetData() ????
    BoolData = pData1->GetData() ????
}
```

Now comes the problem:

How do I get the data from the concrete classes? I have only base class pointers, so I would need to define an abstract getter method in DataInterface. But the signature of the getter method wouold vary from subclass to subclass. For example one time I need to return an integer, one time I need to return a bool type.

Please give me a hint, this problem drives me nuts :/

Answer (score 2):

Make a non-virtual `GetData()` member on each derived class. Then, if you know for certain the actual class of your objects, you can simply perform a static cast and call `GetData()`:

```
int intData = static_cast<IntegerData*>(pData2)->GetData();
```

If you don't know the class, then you need to perform a dynamic cast and check its result:

```
if (IntegerData* _pData2 = dynamic_cast<IntegerData*>(pData2))
{
  int intData = _pData2->GetData();
  // Do stuff with the int
}
else if (BinaryData* _pData2 = dynamic_cast<BinaryData*>(pData2))
{
  bool binaryData = _pData2->GetData();
  // Do stuff with the bool
}
```

Comment: Hm. Usually I don't know the actual class where the base class pointer points to because I use factory classes. Your dynamic casting approach is interesting. I wonder if it is good practice? :)

Comment: Usually you want to avoid `dynamic_cast`; it has some overhead, and is often an indication that your interface design is flawed. But if you lose knowledge about the actual type of the object quickly after creation, there is not much more you can do. Except for if you know the destination of the data on creation of the objects by your factory, then you could use icepack's `SendData' method.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure this is a **"good" practice** but here is one way to solve this.
One advantage with this is that if you try to get the wrong type of data you can get custom error messages. And you can avoid casts (I am not a fan of them).

```
class DataInterface
{
public:
  DataInterface();
  ~DataInterface();

  virtual void FetchData(void) = 0;
  virtual void ProcessData(void) = 0;
  virtual void ClearData(void) = 0;
  virtual int getIntData() { // Error message }
  virtual bool getBoolData() { // Error message }
};

class BinaryData: public DataInterface
{
public:
    BinaryData();
    ~ BinaryData();

    virtual void FetchData(void);
    virtual void ProcessData(void);
    virtual void ClearData(void);
    virtual int getIntData() { // Error message }
    virtual bool getBoolData() { return m_boolData; }

private:
    bool m_boolData;
}

class IntegerData: public DataInterface
{
public:
    IntegerData();
    ~ IntegerData();

    virtual void FetchData(void);
    virtual void ProcessData(void);
    virtual void ClearData(void);
    virtual int getIntData() { return m_intData; }
    virtual bool getBoolData() { // Error message }

private:
    int m_intData;
}


int main()
{
    int IntegerData;
    bool BoolData;
    DataInterface *pData1 = new BinaryData();
    DataInterface *pData2 = new IntegerData();  

    pData1->FetchData();
    pData2->FetchData();

    pData1->ProcessData();
    pData2->ProcessData();

    // now I want to get the data of pData1 and pData2, for example to write it into a file, show in visualization, ...
    IntegerData = pData2->GetIntData();
    BoolData = pData1->GetBoolData();
    BoolData = pData2->GetBoolData() // This will tell you that you are trying to get bool from int class.
}
```

---

---

### Here is one way of handling it with templates.

```
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class DataInterface
{
public:
    DataInterface(T d) : data(d) {}

    virtual T GetData() = 0;
protected:
    T data;
};

class BinaryData : public DataInterface<bool>
{
public:
    BinaryData(bool b) : DataInterface<bool>(b) {} 

    virtual bool GetData() {return data;}

};

class IntegerData: public DataInterface<int>
{
public:
    IntegerData(int i) : DataInterface<int>(i) {} 

    virtual int GetData() {return data;}

};


int main()
{
    int myint;
    bool mybool;
    DataInterface<bool> *pData1 = new BinaryData(true);
    DataInterface<int> *pData2 = new IntegerData(1);  


    // now I want to get the data of pData1 and pData2, for example to write it into a file, show in visualization, ...
    myint = pData2->GetData();
    mybool = pData1->GetData();

    cout<<myint<<" "<<mybool<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I think it's rather bad practice because the interface class now has dependencies to its subclasses. Each time a new subclass (e.g. a new datatype) is added the interface class needs to be modified.

Comment: Yep exactly. You need to know a bit about the concrete classes. It depends on your need.

Comment: Btw you can also implement the base class as a template class and specialize it for each subclass.

Comment: Can you give me a quick example on how to do that?

Comment: Note that the template approach requires you to know the data type at each point you deal with a DataInterface pointer. And you can't stick objects of different types into standard containers anymore. If that's not an issue, it is the more efficient option.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass your data to another entity, you need an abstraction of it.
There are 2 common ways to achieve this:

**1:**
Use `void*`.

```
class DataInterface
{
public:
   ...
   virtual void* GetData() = 0;
};

class BinaryData: public DataInterface
{
public:
   virtual void* GetData() { return &m_boolData; }

private:
    bool m_boolData;
};
```

In `main` use it like this:

```
int main()
{
    bool BoolData;
    DataInterface *pData1 = new BinaryData();

    pData1->FetchData();
    pData1->ProcessData();
    BoolData = *(bool*))pData1->GetData());
}
```

Advantage of this approach is in its simplicity.
Disadvantages are direct access to internal of an object (breaking encapsulation) and also misuse of polymorphism (why do you need an interface if you eventually cast to a type related to a concrete derivative?)

**2:**

A more robust way is to not send the raw data to a client from out of your concrete object but to make a communication with clients an additional role of the object.

```
class DataInterface
{
public:
   ...
   virtual void SendData() = 0;
};

class BinaryData: public DataInterface
{
public:
   ...
   virtual void SendData() 
   {
        //do your stuff here, you know the exact type of your data
   }
};

int main()
{
    bool BoolData;
    DataInterface *pData1 = new BinaryData();

    pData1->FetchData();
    pData1->ProcessData();
    pData1->SendData();
}
```

Note, this is a very stripped example but it demonstrates the idea. Normally, in a real use case you would register clients with you class and send the data to them via a defined interface.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way of achieving this is to design your base class so that it returns a variant type. A variant is a discriminated union container, which holds an object from an heterogeneous set of types (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/variant.html). Here is a complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class DataInterface
{
public:
    DataInterface(){};
    virtual ~DataInterface(){};

    virtual void FetchData(void) = 0;
    virtual void ProcessData(void) = 0;
    virtual void ClearData(void) = 0;
    virtual boost::variant<bool,int,double,std::string> GetData()=0;
};

class IntResult : public DataInterface{
public:
    IntResult() : resultInt(0){};
    ~IntResult(){};

    virtual void FetchData() override {resultInt = 10;};
    virtual void ProcessData() override {resultInt *= 10;}
    virtual void ClearData() override {resultInt = 0;};

    virtual boost::variant<bool,int,double,std::string> GetData()override{
        return resultInt;
    };

private:
    int resultInt;
};


class StringResult : public DataInterface{
public:
    StringResult() : resultString(""){};
    ~StringResult(){};

    virtual void FetchData() {
        resultString= "Hello World";
    }

    virtual void ProcessData() override {
        std::transform(resultString.begin(), resultString.end(),resultString.begin(), ::toupper);
    }

    virtual void ClearData() override {resultString = "";}

    virtual boost::variant<bool,int,double,std::string> GetData() override {
        return resultString;
    };


private:
    std::string resultString;
};





int main() {

    DataInterface* data;

    IntResult* intResult = new IntResult;
    StringResult* stringResult = new StringResult;

    data = intResult;

    data->FetchData();
    data->ProcessData();

    switch(data->GetData().which()){
        case 0:
            std::cout << "found bool: " << boost::get<bool>(data->GetData()) << std::endl;
            break;
        case 1:
            std::cout << "found int: " << boost::get<int>(data->GetData()) << std::endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "found double: " << boost::get<double>(data->GetData()) << std::endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            std::cout << "found string: " << boost::get<std::string>(data->GetData()) << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    data = stringResult;

    data->FetchData();
    data->ProcessData();

    switch(data->GetData().which()){
        case 0:
            std::cout << "found bool: " << boost::get<bool>(data->GetData()) << std::endl;
            break;
        case 1:
            std::cout << "found int: " << boost::get<int>(data->GetData()) << std::endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "found double: " << boost::get<double>(data->GetData()) <<  std::endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            std::cout << "found string: " << boost::get<std::string>(data->GetData()) << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    delete intResult;
    delete stringResult;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that in your case a bool is implicitly convertible to an int so you could simply return ints all the time. The variant approach would work if you need to return truly heterogeneous types. Equivalently you could return a boost any, which can also lets you manipulate a heterogeneous union of types uniformly (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/any.html). Finally if you don't want any dependencies on boost, it is not terribly difficult to roll out your own variant type, which can hold discriminate set of types.